# Define a function that takes as arguments counts of different US coins and prints out the simplest number of bills and coins needed

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, currency, consolidation

I need to define a function consolidate_change that takes as arguments counts of different US coins (similar to the previous function) and prints out the simplest number of bills and coins needed to make that amount.

For example, when called with arguments of 10 quarters, 9 dimes, 8 nickels, and 7 pennies, the function should print:

Number of dollars: 3
Number of quarters: 3
Number of dimes: 1
Number of nickels: 0
Number of pennies: 2
Total amount: $3.87

According to the homework I must also use my value_of_change() method used in the previous section

*The second step is the only part I need help with unless the issue is with my value_of_change() method

We tried a few different functions but my tutor didn't write my value_of_change() method I did so I don't he was following along with my train of thought and I wasn't following his

my code from the previous step: Define a function value_of_change() that takes in named arguments representing amounts of different US coins (quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies)--each of the arguments should have a default value of 0. The function should return the total value in dollars of those coins. For example, 5 quarters, 4 dimes, 3, nickels, and 2 pennies have a value of 1.82 dollars.

```
# defines a variable value_of_change assigning values to quarters, dimes, etc. including test to print

def value_of_change(quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies):
    quarters_value = .25
    dimes_value = .10
    nickels_value = .05
    pennies_value = .01
    total = (quarters * quarters_value) + (dimes * dimes_value) + (nickels * nickels_value) + (pennies * pennies_value)
    print(round(total, 2))
value_of_change(5, 4, 3, 2)
```

second step:
Define a function consolidate_change that takes as arguments counts of different US coins (similar to the previous function) and prints out the simplest number of bills and coins needed to make that amount.

For example, when called with arguments of 10 quarters, 9 dimes, 8 nickels, and 7 pennies, the function should print:

Number of dollars: 3
Number of quarters: 3
Number of dimes: 1
Number of nickels: 0
Number of pennies: 2
Total amount: $3.87
You must use your previous value_of_change() method in this calculation. Hint: think about converting the coins to a giant pile of pennies, and then determining how many (whole number) dollars you can divide them into. Then put those pennies aside, and determine how many (whole number) quarters you can make with the rest, etc.

```
# My code (that isn't working) for the second step

def consolidate_change(change):
    coins = [.25, .1, .05, .01]
    value = 0
    dollars = 1
    quarters = 1
    dimes = 1
    nickels = 1
    pennies = 1

    #change value in pennies
    for i in range (0, 4):
        value = round((value + (change[i] * coins[i])), 2)
    value = round(value)

    #Dollars
    for i in range (0, value):
        if dollars/value == round(dollars/value):
            dollars = dollars/value
        else:
            dollars += 1
    value = round(value)
    print (dollars)

consolidate_change([10, 9, 8, 7])
```

I should be getting a result of

```
Number of dollars: 3
Number of quarters: 3
Number of dimes: 1
Number of nickels: 0
Number of pennies: 2
Total amount: $3.87
```

however my current result is just

```
1.0
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: "simple" is an ambiguous term. Do you mean smallest?

Comment: Ah, I missed that your tutor was mentioned, so this is definitely homework.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt:

```
def consolidate_change(change):
    coins_to_use=[]
    coins = [1, .25, .1, .05, .01]
    for coin in coins:
        coins_to_use.append(int(change//coin))
        change = change%coin
    print(f"Dollars: {coins_to_use[0]}\n Quarters: {coins_to_use[1]}\n Dimes:{coins_to_use[2]}\n Nickels: {coins_to_use[3]}\n Pennies:{coins_to_use[4]} ")

consolidate_change(3.87)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: May want to type cast the division to `int` since you can't have fraction of a coin (at least not legally :) )